# Mysql query with two now() interval

Tags: php, mysql

I'm running a query with two interval's... is this allowed? It's not working for me nor is it outputting any errors. Please help:

```
`status`=1 AND `coupon_date`<=now()-interval 3 HOUR AND `status_date`<=`coupon_date`+interval 12 MINUTE AND `device_id` NOT IN ('357518056780380','353300063955410','170247916')
```

Comment: Can you post the error too?

Comment: please show example data

Comment: You should use DATE_ADD function

Comment: Are you sure there are results which satisfy the condition?